# Special charaters(ã,é,etc...) are not displayed in logcat android studio

Tags: android, special-characters, android-logcat

I am receiving response in xml from link (http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=01427-001) i have DOM parser code to parse it but it shows me output like this.

```
S�o Paulo
Jardim Am�rica
```

I also tried

```
URLDecoder.decode("S�o Paulo", "utf-8");
```

but it is not working. I want to display it as it is like São Paulo, Jardim América.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the xml file that you receive it starts with this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
```

which makes clear, it is encoded in ISO-8851-1 and not UTF-8. The problem therefore seems to be in your parsing code.

Comment: when i run the above url in postman then i was able to see that it uses encoding="iso-8859-1". can you let me know how can i get  "São Paulo" from "S�o Paulo"

Comment: You have to fix the mistake in the "DOM parser code" you have. I don't know what you used there.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. what i earlier done was used the Aynctask. When I changed the code and call service using Volly lib it was done with some more code. By the way thanks for your replay and giving the time.